# Force grep to grab matching line twice

Tags: awk, grep, duplicates

Assume that I have:

```
Z 10  
Z 11  
Y 10
```

I used:

```
$ grep "Z" <above_file> -A 1
Z 10  
Z 11  
Y 10
```

How can I get it to return:

```
Z 10  
Z 11  
Z 11  
Y 10
```

In essence if `grep` sees that the next line also matches the pattern, I want it duplicated.  Is the best/only solution to manually go through line by line or uses a complex `awk` statement with conditionals?  There's further processing after this step, but this is the edge case that is holding me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'f{print; f=0} /Z/{print; f=1}' file
Z 10
Z 11
Z 11
Y 10
```

#### How it works

Awk implicitly reads through the input file one line at a time.  The script uses a single variable, `f`, which is true (non-zero) if the previous line matched `Z`.

- `f{print; f=0}`

  If `f` is non-zero, print this line and set `f=0`.
- `/Z/{print; f=1}`

  If this line matches the regex `Z`, then print this line and set `f=1`.

Note that there is no need to initialize `f`.  In awk, undefined variables default to either zero (in a numeric context) or an empty string (in a character context). In either case, an undefined variable is logical-false.

Comment: Does f automatically initialize to non-zero?

Comment: @TriHard8 Yes.  In awk, undefined variables default to either zero (in a numeric context) or an empty string (in a character context).  In either case, an undefined variable is logical-false.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would do too:

```
$ sed -n ':check /^Z/ {p; n; h; p; x; b check}' file
```

-- `:check` is a label for branching, for lines matching `/^Z/` (so, starting with `Z`) `sed` goes through loop:

1. `p`rint the line *(= print the matched line)*
2. go to `n`ext one
3. copy it to the `h`old buffer
4. `p`rint it *(= print the line after matched)*
5. e`x`change the line, i.e. move `h`old buffer back *(= return the line after matched one)*
6. `b`ranch to `check` to repeat the whole process if the line matches `^Z` *(= check it)*

In principle, `sed` should be good with this kind of recursion (`sed` doesn't store any stacks, right?), but it may not be.
Also I'm not sure if the script is really correct :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check when I'm in the office tomorrow.  I love sed and awk commands as I'm just learning them.  One question, though...Do I need to type out `print` where you have `p` and `next` where you have `n` for instance?  Or does sed automatically know those flags?

Comment: @TriHard8 nope, in fact you cannot type a full word like `print` -- all sed's commands are one-letter. Though the letters are mnemonic for words describing the command: `p` for print, `s` for substitute etc.
And a bit of advertising for a grand sed tutorial: [Grymoire's](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) by Bruce Barnett. He also has one on AWK.